# how to wrap radians between -pi and pi with mod?

Tags: c++, modulo

I'd like to wrap radians between -pi/pi.

This is the actual code I [did](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dfd1b87822979ef), which work:

```
radians > gPIf ? radians - g2PIf : radians < -gPIf ? radians + g2PIf : radians;
```

But I don't like it too much. Tried with mod, but it seems I've problem with negative values:

```
std::fmod(radians + gPIf, g2PIf) - gPIf
```

Is there any "mod" that works also with negative number?

i.e. -20 mod 360 with OS calculator return 340 :)

Comment: Edit reverted. [tag:mod] is the topic of the question.